# How to show a table view header's label in the left part of the same table view cell ?

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I know that it's possible in the collection view with horizontal scroll style but I need this as vertical one.I was tryed to set table view height to 0,rotate the header label but when I set the negative constraint to the label its not showing due to hierarchy of the views.After that,I was tryed to bring the label to front,too.If you don't understand clearly,I can explain with some screenshots or the source codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a headerView and add a label to it and set the text alignment of the header view to left or as per your need.

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50))
    headerView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    let myLabel = UILabel()
    myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.width - 70, 50)
    myLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(18)
    myLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    myLabel.textAlignment = .Left
    myLabel.text = "This is a left alignmen" 
    headerView.addSubview(myLabel)
    return headerView
    }
```

You can go through the[Apple Documentation for Table view](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview).
[image]

This is header view that have left alignment for the header view.

Comment: We are not talking about the same things.Maybe I could not explain clearly anyway, look at this; https://imgur.com/a/H3Xpc

Comment: Ok i got it you want your header view on left and table view cells on right. am i correct..?And only your cells need to be scrolled ?

Comment: Yes. You got me,I think,if I can get the label out inside the header view, everything will be solved.

Comment: Trick here,I set the header view height to 1, then the label doesn't goes out even if it has negative constant constraint.I tryed the clipToBounds,bringSubViewToFront methods.However, all of them did not work.

Comment: Ok tell tell me first..What have you gained till now..As you have shown in your screen shot.What you need now.?Is the thing you need in your screen shot.?

Comment: I want this https://imgur.com/a/9w0GQ   I'm here https://imgur.com/a/spzzd

Comment: Forget about data source by the way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160670/discussion-between-niroj-and-tolga-taner).